# Getting an exception when try to use NTPClient in a custom class (ESP8266)

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm getting an exception (see below) when I try to use NTPClient in my custom class RealTimeService. Please advise why and how to fix it. Thank you.

File RealTimeService.h:

```
#ifndef RealTimeLib
#define RealTimeLib

#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

class RealTimeService {
  private:
    NTPClient _ntp;
    NTPClient _createNtpClient();
    void _update();
  public:
    RealTimeService();
    void begin();
};

#endif
```

File RealTimeService.cpp:

```
#include "RealTimeService.h"

RealTimeService::RealTimeService() : 
  _ntp(_createNtpClient())
{
}

NTPClient RealTimeService::_createNtpClient() {
  WiFiUDP udp;
  NTPClient ntp(udp, "pool.ntp.org", 3600, 86400000);
  return ntp;
}

void RealTimeService::begin() {
  _update();
}

void RealTimeService::_update() {
  _ntp.begin(); // Throws an exception
  if(_ntp.update()) {
    long time = _ntp.getEpochTime();
  } else {
    Serial.print("Failed to get time from server.\n");
  }
}
```

File WebServerSecure.ino:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "RealTimeService.h"


#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "Sedmikraska"
#define STAPSK  "38098246"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

RealTimeService realTime;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  realTime.begin();
}

void loop(void) {
  delay(1000);
}
```

It throws an exception in function RealTimeService::_update() at line _ntp.begin();

```
User exception (panic/abort/assert)
```

And the decoded stack is:

```
0x4020714a: HardwareSerial::begin(unsigned long, SerialConfig, SerialMode, unsigned char, bool) at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266\HardwareSerial.cpp line 51
0x4020804c: __unhandled_exception_cpp() at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 229
0x4020a07c: NTPClient::begin(int) at C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NTPClient\NTPClient.cpp line 61
0x40202544: NTPClient::begin() at C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NTPClient\NTPClient.cpp line 53
0x40201028: RealTimeService::_update() at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_506039\sketch\RealTimeService.cpp line 20
0x40201b04: ESP8266WiFiSTAClass::status() at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp line 634
0x40201058: RealTimeService::begin() at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_506039\sketch\RealTimeService.cpp line 16
0x4020115c: setup() at C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\WebServerSecure/WebServerSecure.ino line 23
0x40208224: loop_wrapper() at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 194
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `udp` in `RealTimeService::_createNtpClient()` and pass it to `NTPClient`. `NTPClient` will continue to need it after `RealTimeService::_createNtpClient()` returns, but `udp` will become invalid. Even if `NTPClient` copies it, its destructor is called, invalidating the resources it used.

You need to change `udp` to be an instance variable so that it will survive as long as `_ntp` does.

```
class RealTimeService {
  private:
    WiFiUDP _udp;
    NTPClient _ntp;
...
```

and

```
NTPClient RealTimeService::_createNtpClient() {
  NTPClient ntp(_udp, "pool.ntp.org", 3600, 86400000);
```

Your code is also calling `_ntp.begin()` repeatedly. You should ensure that the NTP library you're using allows for this; sometimes libraries are written so that their `begin()` method can only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@romkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670348/romkey)'s answer, you could probably skip `_createNtpClient` altogether and move the initialization of the fields in the constructor. Something more compact, like

```cpp
#ifndef RealTimeLib
#define RealTimeLib

#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>

class RealTimeService {
  private:
    WiFiUDP _udp;
    NTPClient _ntp;
    ...
  public:
    RealTimeService();
    ...
};

#endif
```

```cpp
#include "RealTimeService.h"

RealTimeService::RealTimeService() :
  _udp(),
  _ntp(_udp, "pool.ntp.org", 3600, 86400000)
{
}

...
```